# Regex to match substring of file path

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression in Perl that matches a specific part of the file path.

Input string:

```
/usr/local/bin/mybinary
```

Output it has to match to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

My Regular expression is :

```
(\ /.*\ /)
```

It is matching  `/usr/local/bin/`, but the `/` after `bin` should be removed.

Comment: See [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you still want regex so 
   `(.*)\/

will do the job :)

https://regex101.com/r/tK4mP7/1

Comment: it should remove binary and the forward slash from the path.

Comment: it does - see the link for the sample

Answer (score 4):

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) can do this for you:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(dirname);

my $in  = '/usr/local/bin/mybinary';
my $out = dirname($in);
print "$out\n";

__END__

/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're fiddling with paths, using `Path::Tiny` is highly recommended. It has just about all the methods you could want for retrieving absolute/relative path names, basenames, and many others including parent...

```
use Path::Tiny;
my $path = path('/usr/local/bin/mybinary');
say $path->parent; # OUTPUT: '/usr/local/bin'
```

**Update:** Old man advice

I know you said (in your comment to `toolic`'s answer) that you are learning regex and wanted to use them instead of a function. Part of learning regular expressions is also learning where they are not a good fit, or are overkill for the problem. In this case, a substring of the path from `index` 0 to the `rindex` (right index) of '/' would be more efficient.

```
my $string = '/usr/local/bin/mybinary';
say substr($string, 0, rindex($string, '/') ); # OUTPUT: '/usr/local/bin'
# or get the child
say substr($string, rindex($string, '/') + 1); # OUTPUT: 'mybinary'
```

A lot of perl beginners use regex captures or `split` for problems that can be solved more efficiently using `substr`, along with `index`, `rindex`, and/or `length`. It's worth learning these methods of string manipulation so you can better decide when to use regular expressions.